# If facebook connect user changes email will I be notified?

Tags: php, facebook

I am integrating facebook connect into my signup area of my site, I have a regualr signup which saves a user email and password in DB for signup and now there will be option to signup and login with facebook connect.  I was planning on just adding the email hash that facebook sends to my login table for that user and in there roadmap, this month they sey they aregoing to be giving back the users real email address, anyways there is a flaw, what is facebook  user changes there login on facebook then my email I have for them would be outdated, does facebook send updates to me like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think facebook will send you updates (too much work). Probably sometimes you have to ask for user details and check for changes.

Personally, I don't store the emails coming from facebook (they are proxied, don't?) but I think that you have to make something interesting on your site and ask the email address to the user on your site if you think it's necessaty for your purpose.

I wrote a tutorial about the way I've implemented the facebook login on my community:
http://www.barattalo.it/facebook-connect-tutorial/

bye!
Giulio

Comment: Thanks I am on your site now, some good tutorials.  What I have for my existing userbase is a login table and a profile table so I was going to just take the facebook user's proxied email and add it to my login table and an extra row for facebook ID but in reality it would probably be better if I use some other identifier from facebook that won't ever change.  However in the facebook API rodamap, in they say they are going to send the actual non-proxied email by mid January so I expect anyday now we will get the real email address from facebook

Comment: can't you simply use the facebook user id? it will not change. (I hope facebook will give us the emails, but I don't think they really want or can)